# SQL check if value in database is part of string

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate

Is possible to do sql query which will check if value from database is part of input string?

For example, I have record in database:

```
ID |   NAME
_____________
 1 |  ANDROID
```

and now I would like to check if that value is in string like:
"Android studio" and "Android Jetpack".

So one more time - if "android" contains in "Android studio" return "android"

I know how to do it in opposite side, it will be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM technology WHERE name like "%andr%";
```

Comment: You need to convert your input string into upper case and add % at both ends. If technology.NAME is not all upper case, then convert it to upper case as well.

Comment: As in code - I did it. But question is about opposite situation. I want to check if name contains in "Android studio"or "Android Jetpack", and if contains, return that row

Comment: just do the opposite: WHERE "Android studio" like "%" + name + "%".